# Do I need to copy the .compiled files to the production server?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, web-deployment-project

I'm using a deploy project to deploy my ASP.net web application.
When I build the deploy project, all the .compiled files are re-created.

Do I need to FTP them to the production web server?
If I do a small change do I need to copy all the web site again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my own research, the .compiled files must be copied to the production server, but not needed to copied every time

from [Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/) excellent blog:

> The output from the merge utilitity
>   can combine all markup and CodeBeside
>   code into a single assembly, but you
>   will still end up with the .compiled
>   files which are required for ASP.NET
>   to associate the page requests with a
>   specific class contained in the
>   assembly. However, because the file
>   names generated are fixed you don’t
>   need to update these files unless you
>   add or remove pages. In effect this
>   means that in most situations you can
>   simply update the single assembly to
>   update your Web.
>   [Source](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/AspNetCompilation/AspNetCompilation.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the `.compiled` files by using the [aspnet_merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx) tool with the `-r` option.

> Removes the .compiled files for the main code assembly (code in the App_Code folder). Do not use this option if your application contains an explicit type reference to the main code assembly.

Answer (score -2):

There's nothing special about .compiled files: it's just the actual file with a .compiled extension on the end so that nothing happens if you accidentally double click it.

But if you're seeing .compiled files, you're publishing your app in such a way that it expects to be formally installed- it's not enough to just copy things to production.  You have to run the installer program too.  If this is an app you know is already deployed, that seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: the .compiled files are in the BIN folder. 
I have set the "Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly" option.

So, do you say that I don't need to FTP them?

Comment: No, I'm saying that because you see them at all your deployment probably isn't set up right.

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong. I'm using a Web deployment project and deploying to a temp folder. All the compiled files are generated by the build.

Comment: He's not doing anything wrong, those files are generated by WDP.